# How to write a cleaner code while adding cookies to the webdriver in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

According to the [selenium cookie documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/). The following is the way to add cookie to a driver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

# Adds the cookie into current browser context
driver.add_cookie({"name": "key", "value": "value"})
```

The url needs to be fetched first before adding cookies, which means to see desired changes in the url after adding the cookies the site needs to be re-fetched.

so a typical invocation with the cookies would be like

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

# Adds the cookie into current browser context
driver.add_cookie({"name": "key", "value": "value"})


# refetching the url again after adding the cookies
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
```

I want to know if it is possible to add the cookies and see the desired changes in the url without refetching the url?
Or, in short is it possible to make the code more cleaner and remove one `driver.get()` call?

Note: Adding the cookies before invoking the url will throw a `Message: invalid cookie domain` error

```
Edit: since the site needs to be initially loaded, cookies with same name needs to be deleted before adding, this is another bump.
```

an example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import chrome
import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("www.example.com")
driver.delete_all_cookies()

with open('cookies.json', r) as fh:
  cstring = fh.read()
  jcookies = json.loads(cstring)
  
  for cookie in jcookies:
    driver.add_cookie({"name": cookie["name"], "value": cookie["value"]})
    
driver.get("www.example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `refresh` method

```
driver.get(url)
driver.add_cookie({"name": "example", "value": "example"})
driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score -1):

Well yes, you can send the key F5 to the body to refresh the site instead of opening again i assume, if you dont need to restart the browser but only reload the site.